The Maximum Principle is valid for piecewise continuous functions?
According to $[2]$ we have:
$\textbf{Definition 9. 6. 5 (Maxima and minima).}$ Let $f: X\to \mathbf{R}$ be a function, and let $x_0\in X$. We say that $f$ attains its maximum at $x_0$ if we have $f(x_0)\geq f(x)$ for all $x\in X$ (i.e., the value of $f$ at the point $x_0$ is larger than or equal to the value of $f$ at any other point in $X).$ We say that $f$ attainsits minimum at $x_0$ if we have $f(x_0)\leq f(x).$
$\textbf{Proposition 9. 6. 7}$ (Maximum principle). Let $a< b$ be real numbers, and let $f: [ a, b] \to \mathbf{R}$ $be$ $a$ function continuous on $[ a, b] .$ Then $f$ attains its maximum at some point $x_{max}\in [ a, b]$ ,and also attains its minimum $at$ some point $x_{min}\in [ a, b] .$
And according to $[1]$:
Definition $\mathbf{10.18}$. A function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbf{R}$ is piecewise continuous if there exist real numbers $\alpha=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_k=b$ such that $f$ is continuous in the interval $(x_j-1,x_j)$, for $1\leq j\leq k$, and the lateral $\lim_{x\to a+}f(x),\lim_{x\to b-}f(x)$ $\operatorname{and}\lim_{x\to x_j\pm}f(x)$ exist, for $1\leq j<k.$
If $f:[a,b] \subset \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ is piecewise continuous, then there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in [a,b]$  or equivalently the Maximum Principle is true of piecewise continuous? So:
Question. The Maximum Principle is true for piecewise continuous?
$[1]$ Muniz Neto, A. An Excursion through Elementary Mathematics, Volume I. Springer, 2017.
$[2]$ Tao, T. Analysis I. Third Edition, Springer Singapore, $2016$.

Those statements are not equivalent. It's still true that a piecewise continuous function on an interval is bounded (apply the maximum principle separately to each piece) but it doesn't necessarily attain a maximum or minimum (you can change the values of the function at its extreme points).

You are right. Thanks!

No. Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x)=x$ for $x<\frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$.
However, one can always modify the endpoints on these subintervals (by choosing the larger value of the continuous functions that "meet there") so that maxima exist. The relevant generalization is that the maximum principle holds for upper semi-continuos functions.
